# How to sum lap times in Excel

Tags: excel, time, sum

I have to sum lap times that got this format: mm:ss.milliseconds (e.g 1:27.525)

But I cant find anything to sum these, also keep in mind i want to keep 3 decimals for the milliseconds.

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 2):

It appears your times are actuall text that look like times and not true times.

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(B2:B6,":",".",2))
```

To convert them to true times and adds.

Then format the output cell with a custom format of `[mm]:ss.000`

[image]